# Where do X and Y start at in swing windows

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am trying to center a JLabel at the top of an 800x600 JPanel by doing

```
JLabel name = new JLabel();
name.setBounds(400, 300, 600, 100);
```

However this puts the text in some weird spot which makes me think that the X and Y coordinates start somewhere different. Any ideas?

Comment: usually (0,0) is in the top left corner

Comment: The text will usually be *centered* in the label. So this might cause the confusion here.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/overview/coordinate.html "The top-left corner of a window is 0,0."

Comment: and if you want to center it, you have to supstract the width/2 from `x` if I remember correctly. so `name.setBounds((400 - (600/2)), (300 - 100/2), 600, 100);`

Comment: Or just use a `GridBagLayout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All containers have their own coordinate context, this means that `0x0` is the top/left corner of the container itself, irrelevant of where it's placed in its parent container.

> I am trying to center a JLabel at the top of an 800x600 JPanel

Then use an appropriate layout manager and avoid all the oddities of font metrics, DPI and rendering pipelines which exists across all other systems/OSs

[image: Centered Simply]

*(This example will also adapt to changes in the screen size, and you've not had to do a thing, bonus)*

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test();
  }

  public Test() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new TestPane());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }

  public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    public TestPane() {
      setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
      add(new JLabel("I'm in the middle"));
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(800, 600);
    }

  }

}
```

> at the top of

Whoops, might have misread that

In that case, you could do something like...

```
public TestPane() {
  setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
  GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
  gbc.weighty = 1;
  gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
  add(new JLabel("I'm in the middle"), gbc );
}
```

Another option might be to use a `BorderLayout`

```
public TestPane() {
  setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  JLabel label = new JLabel("I'm in the middle");
  label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
  add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
}
```

which might simplify the layout, as you'd need to use a seperate component for the `CENTER` position instead

See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

> But I have to manual position the component because of reasons ....

99.9% of time, when you think you need to do "absolutely positioning", you don't.  You just need to gain a better understanding of the available layout managers and how and when to use them.

That 0.1% of time you really need "absolutely positioning", you probably don't either, you probably just need a custom layout manager to fill that one edge case (maybe consider MigLayout)

Laying out components effectively is complex process with many, many decisions needing to be made and variable states to take into account.  An entire API has been provided to you to solve this issue, you are wasting your own time, and everyone elses, but not taking advantage of it

Comment: *"either you don't like me"* I don't like you.* But it's a good answer, so plus one. * May or not be playing for effect.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Nobody loves, everybody hates me, think I go write some code ... 